# How can I install android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, operating-system, windows-7-x64

I am using window 7 64 bit and i want to install android studio 2.0 or above version. I am able to successfully install android studio but when i launch it opens but it stuck as shown in below image. It not progressing i waited over long time to open next screen but it got stuck to this point.[image]

I have already installed JDK8 64 bit and applied different solution like setting path as JAVA_HOME and SDK_HOME but it not resolve my problem.it  does not also  any error message through which i can find what is problem. So please help me how can i fix this issue.

After some research,I execute "studio.exe" in cmd from the path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin. and i found below error message.But give any error on running studio64.exe. But problem is same it not progressing, it got stuck as above screen for more than 1 hour.  Please Anybody tell me how to resolve it.

---

[image]

Comment: How long are you letting it sit on this screen before force closing? First time I installed A.S. it got hung but I just let it sit for about 20 minutes and it finally kicked all the way through. Double check and make sure you have the latest version and downloaded it from the [Main Site.](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)  Make sure your computer meets the minimum specifications, AS can be resource intensive at times.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit os and 64-bit java install?   You want to open studio64.exe, not studio.exe (the 32-bit version).  studio64.exe is in the same folder at studio.exe.

Comment: Yeah I run studio64.exe,it does not give any problem like above but it also got stuck as above screen.I waited more than 30 minute but it not progressing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with your processor speed, your RAM size or the file could be corrupt. If not, Did you download from the internet? if yes, what version?

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows 7 having 4GB ram,intel CORE i3 processor of 2.2 GHz and i also downloaded latest android studio (2.2.0.12)from official website of android (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

Comment: Check if you are running some heavier apps. If yes, then close the apps, uninstall the studio, restart your computer and reinstall it again....then give us some report!

Answer (score 0):

I think you got JDK8 with 64-bit, but the android studio is running on 32-bit. I think you should install JDK with 32-bit instead of 64-bit.